# how to accept incoming post to c# web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-webhooks

I am new to c# and looking for some documentation/examples where c# web app can accept incoming post from third parties.

i was reading this blog and found its interesting.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/04/introducing-microsoft-asp-net-webhooks-preview/

are there any other  specific examples/documentation available?
your help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* That being said -or quoted- you can just google "c# web api post example" and you'll get more than what ur looking for.

Comment: Just remember that an ASPX page can receive anything through GET/url data (up to say 2000 characters) or POST/formdata (like 2GB), and it can send anything in return (doesn't need to be a web page at all). You can process the data yourself or use something like WebHooks. If you do it yourself, it's no different than processing a posted form or a URL string. Take a look at QueryString,  https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=c-sharp+handling+post+data , and https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=c-sharp+response+types

Comment: Thanks! @ShannonHolsinger

Comment: All samples are available here: https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 0):

Look at this github project, they have some examples:

https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web API is a framework for building web APIs on top of the .NET Framework.

You need to familiar with Model/Controllers/HttpGet/HttpPost/Json as well. A good article with working basic example at:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api